# How can I force an applications source port?

Tags: networking, kernel, iptables, firewall

I have an application running on a local Linux machine A, that needs to be able to communicate with another machine B, listening on port 12325. Problem arises when devices cannot communicate by default, so I open port 12325 in my ACL, but the source port of application on machine A is randomised. Can I use iptables to specifically translate the source port of an application to be changed to 12325? It always runs under the same user, from the same location.

1. Software isn't open source so I'm unable to force this software side.
2. Opening all ports between machines is not an option.

Comment: While you have a great answer below for how to do what you are asking, I suspect you are asking for the wrong thing. Why do you need a specific source port set? I don't think there is a common case where this is something that you need. If I application is listening on a port and that port is open on the firewall you should be fine.

Comment: @user1794469 Devices in question are PC's connected to 4G routers, with a DMVPN connection to AWS. By design, the VPN spokes cannot communicate at all, over any port, or any protocol. We need to be able to allow a specific port to communicate. Unfortunately because the source port is random, it gets blocked on our DMVPN firewall, and we cannot just open all ports between spokes.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1: Containers

Run the application inside a container with an explicit IP address, and then modify your local firewall rules to allow outbound connections *from that specific ip address*. This way you don't need to know the port; you know that rules specific to that ip address will only impact connections from that application and not anything else. This might look like:

```
docker network create app_network --subnet 192.168.51.0/24
docker run --network my_app_network --ip 192.168.51.10 myapimage ...
```

And then in your local firewall, you can add something like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.51.10/32 -j ACCEPT
```

### Option 2: Function interposition

Assuming that your application is a dynamically linked executable, you can use [function interposition](https://jayconrod.com/posts/23/tutorial--function-interposition-in-linux) to override specific library calls. In this case you would probably override the `connect` call in order to call `bind` before establishing the connection. That might look like:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#ifndef TARGET_PORT
#define TARGET_PORT 80
#endif

#ifndef SOURCE_PORT
#define SOURCE_PORT 12000
#endif

int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen) {
    static int (*real_connect)(int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t) = NULL;

    if (!real_connect)
        real_connect = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "connect");


    /*
     * Only makes changes if you are initiating an AF_INET connection to
     * a specific remote port. Modify the logic here, or modify
     * TARGET_PORT and SOURCE_PORT, above, to change this behavior.
     */
    if (
            addr->sa_family == AF_INET &&
            ((struct sockaddr_in *)addr)->sin_port == htons(TARGET_PORT)
       ) {
        const int enable = 1;

        // Set SO_REUSEADDR, otherwise subsequent connections will fail until
        // the socket exits the TIME_WAIT state.
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) < 0)
            return -1;

        struct sockaddr_in sin;
        sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        sin.sin_port = htons(SOURCE_PORT);

        if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return real_connect(sockfd, addr, addrlen);
}
```

Compile the code to a shared library:

```
gcc -shared -ldl -fPIC connect_with_port.c -o connect_with_port.so
```

And then activate it with `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./connect_with_port.so nc google.com 80
```

If you were to run `tcpdump` while executing the above command you would see that connections originate with port `12000`.